# spring integration error handling different types

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am using spring integration XML and want to know what is the best way to deal with error handling.

I am connecting to s3 using `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` and then transforming the csv file from s3 bucket.

Potential errors that can happen are:

1. Transformation Exception could happen if a line in the file is not valid and so can throw a custom error:

`LineTransformationException`

2. What if on s3 bucket an image file is placed by mistake and again could get Transformation Exception
3. s3 could be down and could get

Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:4572 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed:  Connection refused

And the list of many known and unknown errors can go on...

1. So what is the **best** way to handle all these errors? Through custom `ErrorHandler` or `exception-type-router`
2. If doing it through `ErrorHandler` then how to cater for so many Exceptions.
3. And is there a catch-all exception handler?

   public class ErrorHandler {

   public void handleFailure(Message errorMmessage) {

   ```
   MessagingException payload = (MessagingException) errorMmessage.getPayload();

   LOG.info(">>--- Exception --- " + payload.getCause());
   ```

   }}

or

```
 <int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel"
                           default-output-channel="nullChannel">

    <int:mapping exception-type="com.api.exception.TransformationException"
                 channel="transformErrorChannel"/>

    <int:mapping exception-type="com.amazonaws.SdkClientException"
                 channel="clientErrorChannel"/>

</int:exception-type-router>

<int:channel id="transformErrorChannel"/>

<int:service-activator ref="errorHandler"
                       method="handleFailure"
                       input-channel="transformErrorChannel"
                       output-channel="nullChannel"/>

<int:service-activator ref="clientErrorHandler"
                       method="handleFailure"
                       input-channel="clientErrorChannel"
                       output-channel="nullChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` together with its `<poller>` can be configured with the `error-channel`. By default the polling error (and therefore all the downstream) are routed to the global `errorChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Thanks. I've gone with custom error handler with two methods one to handle transformation exception e.g. messageHandlingFailure(Message<MessageTransformationException> message)  and the other to handle any other type errors e.g. handleFailure(Message<MessagingException> message). Do you think this is the right thing to do?

Comment: Also how to disable the LoggingHandler? as its continously output the stage trace.

Comment: You can declare you own `errorChannel` bean. This way that `LoggingHandler` will be disabled.